# android - dynamically changing the position of an imageview

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

i'm currently using the matrix method to implement drag and pinch zoom for an image (image A)

Now i want a part of image A to be clickable so i put another imageview (image B) over image A and set the layout_margins for it in the xml file.

My question is...is there a way to dynamically change my layout_margins as i'm scaling my image for drag and pinch zoom?

I guess the simpler question is...how do i dynamically set the layout_margins for an imageview?

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/map"
     android:scaleType="matrix" />

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/dundas_station"
       android:layout_width="75px"
       android:layout_height="75px"
       android:layout_marginTop="337px"
   android:layout_marginLeft="373px"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:src="@drawable/google_maps_icon"
       android:scaleType="matrix"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use following code snippet. Don forget to import 
"android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams" or marginal layout params.

```
ImageView image;
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(100,0, 0,0);

// OR
params.topMargin= 100;
image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [setMargins](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html)